# NHibernate DetachedCriteria.SetFirstResult?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I found an example of implementing the repository pattern in NHibernate on the web, and one of the methods uses this code to get the first result of a query:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindAll(DetachedCriteria criteria, int firstResult, int numberOfResults, params Order[] orders)

{
    criteria.SetFirstResult(firstResult).SetMaxResults(numberOfResults);
    return FindAll(criteria, orders);
}
```

But VS intellisense isn't picking up this method from DetachedCriteria. Does anyone know if this is possible with DetachedCriteria? I'm using NHibernate version 1.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be available until an ISession is bound.  For instance, it's not on DetachedCriteria, but it is available on the ICriteria that is returned from the **GetExecutableCriteria** method.

Answer (score 0):

never mind, I think I got it:

```
criteria.GetExecutableCriteria(_session).SetFirstResult(firstResult).SetMaxResults(numberOfResults);
```